# Floating Action Menu

Tags: android

I am using https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button. How can I change the icon of the floating action menu, not the floating action button?

```
<!--This is the floating action menu-->

android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
fab:fab_shadow="true">
<!--fab:fab_icon="@drawable/pencil_ico" in this doesn´t work>-->

<!--this are the floating action buttons-->
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!--fab:fab_icon="@drawable/pencil_ico" here it´s work-->
    fab:fab_shadow="true"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="#BFD22B"
    fab:fab_title="Action A"/>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:fab_shadow="true"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="#BFD22B"
    fab:fab_title="Action B"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="#ff7e9024"/>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_c"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:fab_shadow="true"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="#BFD22B"
    fab:fab_title="Action C"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Style.xml under values folder you have the below code

```
<style name="menu_labels_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

You can change the icon of floating action menu by using the line

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/your_icon_or_your_selector</item>
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to change the icon of the label, i mean the icon of the floating action button parent not the childs, the one who displays the others floating buttons

Comment: @AngelRodríguez Why's the answer marked as accepted? Did that work? I'm looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

getMenuIconView is the method you need.

```
floatingActionMenu.getMenuIconView().setImageDrawable(Your Drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest using [this](https://github.com/toanvc/FloatingActionMenu-Animation/) library which is derived from com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu only.

You could change the icon by using following attribute in FloatingActionMenu:

```
fab:fab_menuIcon="@drawable/sort"
```

You can however use all the features of the parent library (com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu).